Code with random module in python showing this error
import random

for i in range(3):
    print(random.random())

    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "j:\Visual Studio Code\Python\random.py", line 1, in <module>
    import random
  File "j:\Visual Studio Code\Python\random.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(random.random())
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

module not callable

Did you happen to call your script random.py? If so, don’t name your script the same as an existing module

you should rename your script file to something other than "random.py". Choose a different name that doesn't conflict with Python's built-in modules. After renaming the file, your code should work fine.
